# Changing Boolean Solver in 2.78?

Tags: modifiers

How do I change the Boolean Solver (bmesh/carve) in blender 2.78?

Im using the difference boolean and the result is strange. i want to try the other solver, but I cannot figure out how to change it? Ive seen other people with the option to change it right next to the operation: box, but I dont have that.

What can I do to change the solver?

[image: solver option is missing]

Comment: during development, the Blender devs had this feature in for quite a while, then removed it because there were severe issues found, and just before the release of the final Blender 2.78 they re-added it. Are you using the stable release downloaded from Blender.org or one of the release candidates stil?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Carve]

Check that you are really in version 2.78 - the option should be directly under...